# Passing values through URL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

component.php

```
<script>
   jq142(document).ready( function() {
       new Paginator('<?php echo HOST_URL; ?>component_ajax.php');
});        
</script>
```

I need to pass the id from component.php file to component_ajax.php file. component_ajax.php will load on the component.php file.

component_ajax.php

```
$coid = $_GET['id'];
$products = $productObj->getFrontProductsbyComponents( $coid );
```

Explain me to that how to pass id to `$coid`?

Comment: new Paginator('<?php echo HOST_URL; ?>component_ajax.php?id="your id"');

Comment: so you want to pass the $coid to the component.php

Comment: @user2877903 you should follow the Ruturaj

Comment: tried 
new Paginator('<?php echo HOST_URL; ?>component_ajax.php?id="your id"');

But it is not working.

Comment: This componet_ajax.php file loading using Ajax.

Comment: what error you are getting in ajax?

Comment: no any errors. not loading products. Please check the my testing URL:
http://www.ngo.accura-tech.com/component/2/developer-components

Comment: in here Iam using Ajax pagination also.

Comment: As I think thats the reason to do not pass the values through the URLs

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the id to the component_ajax.php URL.

```
new Paginator('<?php echo HOST_URL; ?>component_ajax.php?id=<?php echo $your_id; ?>');
```

If the ID you need to pass to component_ajax.php is in JavaScript instead of PHP, append the ID to the URL with javascript.

```
<script>
    var your_id = 123;
    jq142(document).ready( function() {
        new Paginator('<?php echo HOST_URL; ?>component_ajax.php?id=' + your_id);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is displayed when you `print_r($_REQUEST)` inside component_ajax.php?

Comment: That tells me the id is not being passed at all (as opposed to being a blank value), which suggests maybe your Paginator javascript might be removing the id parameter from the URL. Can you tell me more about the Paginator javascript? Is it custom code or is it a third party library with documentation you could link to?

Comment: http://www.aplusdesign.com.au/misc/pagination/pagination_jquery.php#p=1 This is the script I used to...

Comment: Pass the parameters in as an argument. `var ajaxParams = {"id":<?php echo $your_id ?>}; new Paginator('<?php echo HOST_URL; ?>component_ajax.php', {"xParams": ajaxParams});`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the ID in to your Paginator object as an argument.

```
var ajaxParams = {"id":<?php echo $your_id ?>};
new Paginator('<?php echo HOST_URL; ?>component_ajax.php', {"xParams": ajaxParams});
```

[Source](http://www.aplusdesign.com.au/misc/pagination/pagination_jquery.php#p=1)